# FFMPEG - Automatic Stream Copy Then Encode On Fail

Tags: ffmpeg

I've embarked on a mission to get rid of all of my MKV files since the MP4 container works better for me.  So to that end, I did some research and wrote a small script that searches my data files for MKVs and stream copies them to MP4.  The script works most of the time, but I get the occasional file that fails and since the script deletes the originals, I lose the file completely.

I'd like to modify the script in two ways:

(1) Before deleting the original file, check that the converted file is greater than zero.

(2) If the converted file is zero (failed) then run an FFMPEG command to re-encode the original file using default values utilizing Intel Quick Sync hardware encoding, then delete the original as usual and go on to the next file in the list.

Here's what I have so far...

```
@ECHO OFF
cls
echo This script automatically converts MKV video files to MP4.
echo.
echo Changing directory to data drive (Z:).
echo.
Z:
echo Retrieving list of MKV files...
echo.
dir /b /s *.mkv > MKV-Files.txt
echo MKV list compiled.
echo.
echo Converting files to MP4...
echo.
FOR /F "delims=;" %%F in (MKV-Files.txt) DO (
echo Converting "%%F"
echo.
C:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%F" -movflags faststart -codec copy "%%~dF%  %~pF%%~nF.mp4"
echo.
echo Conversion successful.
echo.
echo Deleting "%%F"
echo.
del "%%F" /F 
)
echo Job completed.
echo.
echo Exiting...
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this substitution:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%F" -abort_on empty_output -movflags faststart -codec copy "%%~dF%  %~pF%%~nF.mp4" || ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%%F" -movflags faststart -c:v h264_qsv -c:a copy "%%~dF%  %~pF%%~nF.mp4"
```

You may want to disable subtitle or data tracks as MP4 has limited support for them. Add `-dn` and `-sn` for that.

Comment: Thanks Mulvya! Seems to be working fine.  I'm new to scripting so I had to look up the double pipe.  I found Unix info that said only execute the second command if the first one fails.  Does this also work for Windows scripting?